# Things he knew were not true, (that) he knew could not be true

Tags: conjunctions, optional-that

[Things he knew were not true, (**that**) he knew could not be true](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=669&t=27722)

Is it grammatical to leave out *that* here?

Comment: The text is almost meaningless, and not something a native Anglophone would be likely to say. But syntactically speaking ***either or both*** instances of the relativizer ***that*** (before each instance of ***he knew***) can be present or not. All 4 permutations are "valid", but it's hardly meaningful to ask which is more "elegant". None of them are.

Comment: This has already been exhaustively discussed [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/574640/things-he-knew-were-not-true-he-knew-could-not-be-true?noredirect=1#comment1432420_574640). The OP is not quoting the full sentence.